# Spigot/Bukkit - Get Inventory of Chest - Java

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I tried to save a `Chest`, so I have a `BlockState` and a `Inventory`. The `BlockState` is no problem, but in the `Inventory` he always saves `0` for the Amount of a `ItemStack`.

```
if (BlockState instanceof Chest) {
    Chest chest = (Chest) bs;
    Inventory inv = chest.getBlockInventory();
    System.out.println(inv.getItem(0).getAmount());
}
```

In the Console `0` is printed, also when the `Chest` is like this:[image: Screenshot | Chest]

EDIT:
Now I have this:

```
BlockState nbs = bs.getBlock().getState();
System.out.println(((Chest) nbs).getBlockInventory().getItem(0).getAmount());
```

But now I get this Error:

```
[21:16:25 ERROR]: null
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'set' in plugin GlobalSystem vAlpha_0.0.1
    at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:46) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-07c3001]
    at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:141) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-07c3001]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:641) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-07c3001]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:1162) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-07c3001]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:997) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-07c3001]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:45) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-07c3001]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:1) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-07c3001]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-07c3001]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:44) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-07c3001]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.B(MinecraftServer.java:715) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-07c3001]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:374) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-07c3001]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:654) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-07c3001]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:557) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-07c3001]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_73]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.block.CraftBlockState cannot be cast to org.bukkit.block.Chest
    at me.Nightfighter001.GlobalSystem.Methoden.Undo.add(Undo.java:56) ~[?:?]
    at me.Nightfighter001.GlobalSystem.Commands.setzen.onCommand(setzen.java:53) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-07c3001]
    ... 15 more
```

But I don't have any CraftBlockState, I also never imported it!

Maybe it is easier for you to understand, if I explain it a little bit more:
I am developing something like WorldEdit, so I can select Blocks and change them. For an own `/undo`- and `/redo`-Command, I need to save the old Blocks. I do this in a HashMap. I'm saving BlockStates in ArrayList in the HashMap.

Thank you for your help and sorry for my bad English ;)

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem. When using your code, my console prints out "2" which is the correct amount of the first item in the chest (item at index 0). What version of Spigot/Bukkit are you using? Are you sure you were using the latest version of your plugin?

Comment: I use the 1.8.8 which I have created with the BuildTool. And yes I use the latest version of my plugin. Tomorrow I will try some things and maybe rewrite some methods and then tell you if it works. But of course it is very interesting that it works in your plugin... :D

Comment: Yeah, the item at index 0 is definitely the first item in the chest inventory. The only possibility as far as I know is that you get an NPE because there is no `ItemStack` in the first slot, but otherwise I can't see any reason why the item amounts should be 0, unless you're manipulating the `BlockState` in some way.

Comment: Okay, it still doesn't work :/ Here a other line: `System.out.println(((Chest) main.selectedLocs.get(p.getName()).iterator().next().getBlock().getState()).getInventory().getItem(0).getAmount());`. `selectedLocs` is a `HashMap` in wich I save the `Locations` (`selectedLocs = new HashMap<String, Set<Location>>(listSize);`) that are selected by a specified `Player`. And as you can see, I also don't manipulate the `BlockState`... I don't know what I am doing wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom `YAML` files and save values in there and then when you do that you can put the values into inventory

if you don't know what to do it with you can make a `HashMap` and then put the number of the item slot in one value side and the type of it on the other side and you can use Microsoft Excel to store the type of items and there shortcut names and then you can get the custom configuration file and then do a for loop to store the values in the `HashMap`

if this was helpful comment on the post or vote an up for the post so i know that i helped :D

Comment: Sorry, but I know that! I asked why he returns `0` for the Amount of a `ItemStack`. Like I described, `Inventory.getItem(0).getAmount();` returns `0` for the `Inventory` shown in the picture.

Comment: Well i'm sorry i don't know about that. But i got a tip for you check through all the classes that you had made changes to and then read it to yourself. That's at least how i fix errors. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem now by saving the Amount in another List... It's not very elegant, but it works :D

If someone else has a better Idea, please post it!

Thank you very much :)